# $_SESSION, wise to use to hold data?

Tags: php

I was wondering if using $_SESSION['data'] would be a smart way to hold information about a user who is logged in.

For example:

Say i have a game and i want to display their level/exp/username etc, well currently every page load i have to recall the database... so im wondering if i store it in a SESSION i can use a boolean to tell PHP if it needs to re-update its data... thus reducing the amount of MYSQL calls ?

Is this a smart idea of is there some flaw im unaware of ?

Comment: It depends on what is stored and what [lack of] visibility levels are tolerable. The SESSION *is* stored somewhere server-side as well and there are various other caching options: use the work other people have done before inventing your own ;-)

Comment: everything is legit, as long as you know what you are doing... ;)

Comment: @pst i don't know of any other way to store the data to reduce SQL calls :P

Comment: session is not a form of cache

Comment: Look into MySQL caching from PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about competition between database updates? How would you know if the data is not up to date anymore? If this is a straightforward and reserved data to the logged user, allowing him to be logged in only once at a given time, then why not :-)

If you seek an alternative, there's this new thing of local storage, by HTML5

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Well each login it updates - and every time i use a MYSQL update /delet/insert i would edit the $_SESSION accordingly.. unless they have some way to fiddle with it ?

Comment: yeah, this part is fine, but what if another session (S2) updates the data: you wouldn't see it from S1

Comment: what do you mean by another session ?

Comment: this is really theoretical, since I don't know your game restrictions. But let say the action of another player has an incidence on the player we're talking about's datas. You wouldn't see it. My point is to say that anything happening outside your session will be invisible. But maybe this is not supposed to happen.

Comment: Ah i see - no my $_SESSION idea is solely to display output data, which won't have to keep being refreshed via a db call. But can $_SESSION data be edited by a user from their browser?

Comment: no, i don't think, except by using some kind of leaks that you would have to really intentionally want to open for them to exist...